# C++ Largest number in array. Positive and negative

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a task to print maximum int of matrix second line.

Example input:

```
3 2 (n, m)

-1 -2 <- 1 line

4 5 <- 2 line

2 6 <- 3 line
```

Max int in second line is 5. My program prints it. But if second line would be -100 -150, it not works. Sure it is because I have max = 0, but I don't know how to use it properly. I'm a student. Thanks in advance.

It is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, m, max = 0;
  cin >> n >> m;

  int matrix[10][10];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (matrix[1][j] > max) {
        max = matrix[1][j];
      }
    }
  }

  if (max == 0 || n == 1) {
    cout << "No";
  } else {
    cout << max;
  }
}
```

And code works pretty good, unless there are negative numbers in second line

Comment: Remove `max = 0` and add `int max = matrix[1][0];` after your `cin` loop.

Comment: @user11923373 It works! Thank You so much!

Comment: Can somebody explain how this works, and why It is bad to do max = 0?

Comment: Because 0 is greater than any negative number. A side-note, the `for(int i...` loop isn't needed because you only scan one line, `i` is not used anyway (talking about the 2nd nested loop).

Comment: Libraries exist to make your life easier, not harder. The code change works because 0 is an arbitrary value that you chose. Using the first element is much more definitive as a starting  value since all comparisons are now made by numbers in your array, and not a made-up value that may not represent your array.

Comment: Also, this code is broke. If I enter values greater than 10, your program will do weird stuff or just blow up.

Comment: Thank You guys! Have a nice day!

Comment: Wish I could have a nice day. Sadly the Stones were right. You can't always get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct to suspect `max = 0;`. Why is that a problem? Well, first, perhaps you should try to [explain to your rubber duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) why it is correct. As you try to do so, you are likely to express an intent along the lines of *"this value will not make it through the checks"* or *"this value will be replaced in the first iteration of the loop"*. Why? *"Because `matrix[1][j] > max` will be true, so... Hold on, wasn't the problem when `matrix[1][j] > 0` is false? So when `max` is `0`, um... problem?"*

The overall strategy is valid, but there is a requirement that `max` be initialized to a low enough value. There are two common strategies I can think of at the moment.

1. Use a value that is [as low as possible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest) for the type you are using. That is:
   `int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();`
2. Use the value from the first iteration of the loop. No need to provide a value that is just going to be replaced anyway. There are some caveats for this, though. The most relevant for your example can be expressed as a question: what if there is no first iteration? (Perhaps there is only one row? Perhaps there are no columns?) Also, **you would need to initialize `max` between your loops**, after the matrix has been given values.
   `int max = (n > 1  &&  m > 0) ? matrix[1][0] : /* what value do you want here? */;`